# How do I get my rep points from a question I asked as an unregistered user?

Tags: support, status-completed, user-accounts

I asked [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/about-schengen-90-180-rule) on Travel.SE as an unregistered user last year. Since then I became a regular visitor here and created this account. Recently, I stumbled upon that old post which is now one of the frequented questions on Travel.SE. I also noticed that the question and the top response (also by me) gained some rep points. Now I regret not registering earlier. Is it possible to add that post (and the rep points) to my current profile? I am quite certain that I used the same e-mail id to post that question as the one I am currently registered under.

Answer (score 8):

Use [the contact form](https://travel.stackexchange.com/contact) to get in touch with Stack Exchange staff, and select the "I need to merge user profiles" in the combo box. Supply some details as necessary, and point to this meta question as well, if you like. You may need to provide proof that the question you asked was indeed yours, if that is not immediately obvious from what you have supplied as contact details. The SE staff will take it from there.

Comment: I have contacted them. Thanks for your reply.